# Will the p value become useless in such case: logistic regression with perfect separation?

Tags: logistic, p-value, separation

I think I understand the perfect separation problem in logistic regression and answered my own question in this post from optimization perspective.

[Is there any intuitive explanation of why logistic regression will not work for perfect separation case? And why adding regularization will fix it?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239928/is-there-any-intuitive-explanation-of-why-logistic-regression-will-not-work-for)

However, I still do not understand the p-value in such case. I saw all the values in R is `<2e-16` for thousands coefficients. For example

```
             Estimate Std. Error    z value Pr(>|z|)
    c1       -1.524e+15  4.701e+07  -32413747   <2e-16 ***
    c2       -4.226e+15  4.735e+07  -89262659   <2e-16 ***
    c3       -2.932e+15  6.302e+07  -46524709   <2e-16 ***
    c4       -2.808e+15  4.098e+07  -68505362   <2e-16 ***
    c5        2.141e+15  7.796e+07   27470901   <2e-16 ***
    c6       -5.617e+14  7.295e+07   -7699884   <2e-16 ***
    c7       1.046e+15  7.135e+07   14654699   <2e-16 ***
    c8       1.797e+15  4.161e+07   43176668   <2e-16 ***
    c9       -1.443e+14  7.788e+07   -1852414   <2e-16 ***
    c10      2.095e+15  9.287e+07   22557866   <2e-16 ***
    c11      4.918e+14  3.600e+07   13659294   <2e-16 ***
    c12      -1.293e+14  4.204e+07   -3076600   <2e-16 ***
    ...      ...        ...         ...         ...
```

Why would that happen? And Can I say the p-values are not longer valid in perfect separation case?

Comment: This isn't answerable till you explain how you're fitting the model & calculating the p-values. The common schoolboy error is using maximum-likelihood fitting together with the Wald approximation to calculate p-values in the presence of separation, typically making them absurdly large.

Answer (score 1):

Loosely speaking your null hypothesis is that the population coefficient(s) is/are zero. Your estimate is infinite. The probability that such a value or more extreme could be drawn from a normal with mean zero and the estimated se as standard deviation is going to be much smaller than anything R is willing to print out.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense to me. But why all coefficients go to infinity? should that be only the on the feature that can do the perfect separation?

Comment: Well in act some of them are negative infinity. I think if you remove the one you know is perfect the others may look more sensible. Note however that I am _not_ recommending removing predictors when they are perfect.