# How to rescale relative risk

Tags: relative-risk

To examine the association between an exposure and outcome, for example body mass index as exposure and all-cause mortality as outcome, some of studies reported relative risk as a continuous form.  For example, reported relative risk only for 1 unit increment in body mass index. Now, how we can rescale relative risk and estimate it for 2 unit increment? I am trying to conduct a systematic review and meta-analysis but I dont know how we can do this.  And what is such solution for case-control studies?

another example,

association between Mediterranean dietary pattern score and all-cause mortality: score range from 0 to 9 /
number of participants: 1849 / number of death: 553 /
relative risk of all-cause mortality for one unit increment in MED score :
 0.95 (95%CI: 0.91, 1) /

know, relative risk for 2 unit increment in MED score?

Comment: You should fix your keyboard---the caps key obviously is not working.  For now, I edited in caps for you.

Comment: Body mass index has units that are not physical. It is heuristic. If you want to predict anything, I would suggest you employ a physically relevant measurement.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, it all depends on how the relative risk is calculated. [This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/17203/35004) describes how it's done using linear models. If the relative risk is an average over multiple stratification groups, computed using e.g. [The Mantel Haenszel Method](https://wiki.ecdc.europa.eu/fem/w/wiki/the-mantel-haenszel-method), then you cannot infer anything about a unit increase in any of the stratification variables, since they are typically discretized.

Comment: thank you for your answers. but my question is how to convert relative risk per 1 unit or 1.5 unit increment in exposure to relative risk per two unit increment, if the data for multiple categories were not reported in articles.