# Interpretation of effects plot in latent class regression

Tags: multinomial-logit, latent-class, effects

I'm fitting a latent class model with covariates using `poLCA` in `R`. It seems to work fine, but I have some trouble understanding the effects plot made with the `effects` library.

To keep things simple my only covariate will be age. The regression table I get has positive, significant slopes for age for all classes vs. the reference class (class 1).

My primitive understanding is that members of classes 2 and 3 vs. the reference class are expected to have a higher mean age. Stretching things quite a bit I would say that as age increases the probability of belonging to classes 2 and 3 should increase, while as age decreases the probability of belonging to class 1 should increase.

Yet, when I plot the effects everything seems upside down. For class 2 I have a negative "slope" of the predictive probability: the probability of belonging to this class decreases as age increases. That seems to contradict the regression estimates, or at least my interpretation.

I think I'm misunderstanding the `Effects()` output for this model, but maybe I'm misunderstanding the slopes of a multinomial logit. I wouldn't be surprised if both.  Then, **what is a correct interpretation of the `Effects()` for latent class models with covariates?**

Thanks in advance.

## Plots and tables

### Regression table

```
========================================================= 
Fit for 3 latent classes: 
========================================================= 
2 / 1 
            Coefficient  Std. error  t value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)    -1.76241     0.24882   -7.083         0
AGE             0.02661     0.00489    5.443         0
========================================================= 
3 / 1 
            Coefficient  Std. error  t value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)    -0.81100     0.22763   -3.563     0.000
AGE             0.01271     0.00472    2.691     0.007
=========================================================
```

> Raw from poLCA output

### Effects plot

[image]

## Reproducible example

I managed to get the same behavior using a different specification for the example code of `Effects.poLCA` instead of my real data set and model specification. That makes the problem much simpler to reproduce. Table and plot above are outputs of this code:

```
library(poLCA)
library(effects)
data(election)

f2a <- cbind(MORALG,CARESG,KNOWG,LEADG,DISHONG,INTELG, MORALB,CARESB,KNOWB,LEADB)~AGE

set.seed(2019) #to get the same class order

nes2a <- poLCA(f2a, election, nclass=3, nrep=5)

plot(allEffects(nes2a))
```

## Background

[This Q/A](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/362414/interpretation-of-regression-coefficients-in-latent-class-regression-using-polc) is helpfull and related, but not the same problem.