# What is the meaning of having a sum of weights equal to zero?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, regression-coefficients

In my dataset, the target variable has three labels: Normal, suspect, and Pathology.

Using multinomial logistic regression, I calculated the weights for each predictive feature and got something like this:

[image]

When estimating the model, identification
constraints are required on the parameters.
These constraints do not influence the goodness of model fit, odds ratios, estimated
probabilities, interpretations, or conclusions.
Identification constraints do affect the specific
values of parameter estimates. The typical constraints are to set the parameter values of the
baseline category equal to zero (e.g., aj = $\beta_j$ = 0)
or to set the sum of the parameters equal to zero
(e.g., $\sum \beta = 0$).

##### Question: why does the sum of the coefficients equal zero? how does this constraint happen and why is it necessary?

Comment: This *sounds* like a standard characteristic of any multinomial logistic regression--because it estimates odds *ratios* only the differences matter, so (depending on how you specify the model) the software will standardize its outputs to sum to zero--but it would be nice to have you confirm that's what you're doing.  For further explanation follow the links from [this site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=multinomial+logistic+model+exp).

Comment: @whuber Yes.. that is what I'm doing.

Comment: @whuber what do you mean by "because it estimates odds ratios only the differences matter" and "the software will standardize its outputs to sum to zero" ?

Comment: That's all explained in some of the hits in that site search.  Check out the [first one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17196).